# Installing application error in terminal

Tags: command-line

I was going through the Ubuntu FAQ and I came across an antivirus called `clamav`, it was a problem getting the obvious `./configure` command and after the flashing processes in terminal the last line of output was

```
configure: error: OpenSSL not found.
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: As you are a beginner, install clamav via Software Center in Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried installing it with 'sodu apt-get install clamav' and it did download but i dont see the app anywhere

Comment: Have a look  [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) on how to install software in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error you must (as the error implies) install `openssl`. You can achieve this by running the command `sudo apt-get install openssl`.